# Simple Differentiation Problem Involving Area Radius and Circumference

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

A stone is dropped into a pool of water, and the area covered by the spreading ripple increases at a rate of $4 m^2 s^{-1} $.
Calculate the rate at which the circumference of the circle formed is increasing 3 seconds after the stone is dropped.

My method:

$$ \begin{align} 
& \cfrac{dA}{dt}=4\\
& A = \pi \times r \times r \ \text{so} \ \cfrac{dA}{dr} = 2 \times \pi \times r \\
& C = 2 \times \pi \times r \ \text{so} \ \cfrac{dC}{dr} =2 \times \pi \\
& \cfrac{dA}{dt} = \cfrac{dA}{dr} \times \cfrac{dr}{dt} \\
& 4     =  2 \times \pi \times (3) \cfrac{ dr}{dt} \\
& \text{so} \ \cfrac{dr}{dt} = \cfrac{2}{(3 \times \pi)} \\ 
& \text{now} \ \cfrac{dC}{dt} = \cfrac{dC}{dr} \times \cfrac{dr}{dt} \\ 
& \text{so} \  \cfrac{dC}{dt} = 2 \times \pi  \times  \cfrac{2}{(3 \times \pi)}
\end{align} $$

I'm getting $1.3333...$

But the answer is $2.05m/s$ , I don't understand how to get it...

Comment: Perhaps, I think the answer is 2.047 to be more exact...

Comment: You substituted the radius $r=3$ instead of substituting the variable time.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that haha. So how should I have done it then?

Comment: @Fantini: Well-spotted!

Comment: Check my answer. I'm not seeing another approach without integrating. Seems a nasty related rates problem if you've never seen integration... @CameronBuie Thank you!

Comment: I found the same questions here http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=110425
Could that method work? (It is B))

Comment: Yes, it works. Probably how they really intended. Just be careful that the guy in the answer used $t=4$ instead of $t=3$.

Comment: oh ok thanks :) I have to go afk for a while, be back soon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dt}\frac{dC}{dA} $$

$$C=2\pi r= 2\frac{\pi r^2}{r}=2\frac{A}{r} $$ (since $A=\pi r^2 $) and
$$A=\pi r^2 \implies r=\sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}$$

Therefore using the previous 2 results $$C=2 \frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}}=2\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}}\times \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=2\frac{A\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{A}}=2\sqrt{\pi A}$$

$$\therefore \frac{dC}{dA}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{A}}$$

$$\implies \frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dt}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{A}} $$

and since A is changing at a constant rate of $4m^2/s$, $A=4t$.

$$\frac{dC}{dt}=4 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4t}}$$

So at 3 seconds 
$$\frac{dC}{dt}=4\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{12}}\approx2.0466 \ m/s$$

Comment: How did you get C=2A/r and C=2*sqrt(pi*A)? Could you show the working step by step please?

Comment: @lemonrsiow , sure I made some edits. Does that help? Let me know if you need any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

Start from the equation $$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt}$$ using $A(r) = \pi r^2$. We get $dA/dr = 2 \pi r$ and $$4 = 2 \pi r \frac{dr}{dt} \text{ or } r \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$ Write $$r \, dr = \frac{2}{\pi} \, dt$$ and integrate, obtaining $$\int_0^r \rho \, d \rho = \frac{r^2}{2} = \int_0^t \frac{2}{\pi} \tau \, d\tau = \frac{2}{\pi} t.$$ Writing $r$ in terms of $t$ we have $$r = 2 \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}.$$ Now differentiating we obtain $$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$$ and substituting into $$\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{dC}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt}$$ we get $$\frac{dC}{dt} = 2 \pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}.$$ Taking $t=3$ it results $$\frac{dC}{dt} \approx 2,046 \, \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}.$$ **EDIT:** Perhaps a (non-explicit integrating) way to see it is notice the following: $$\frac{d}{dt} (r(t))^2 = 2 r \frac{dr}{dt} \text{ and } \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{2}{\pi} t \right) = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$ Therefore this implies that $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} (r(t))^2 = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{2}{\pi} t \right).$$ Since $r(0) = 0$ you can assert that $$\frac{1}{2} r^2 = \frac{2}{\pi} t$$ and the solution goes as above.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learnt integration yet... Is there a way to do it using only differentiation?

Comment: I'm trying, but haven't figured out another yet. This seems pretty nasty without integration.

Comment: ok, thanks :) I'm thinking of finding the r when A=12m^2 which is after 3 seconds...

Comment: Integrating will be an important step here. I'm also not sure how to do this problem without integration.

Comment: Also, Fantini +1 for such a good work. :)

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Thank you. You did great work putting LaTeX for the OP too!

Comment: Thanks for that. I basically like editing questions, as I have been trying to master in TeX! :)

Comment: @lemonrsiow I'm becoming firmly convinced that you can't solve this without integration. Try talking to whoever gave you the problem. You are given the time but not the radius where this happens. You need to find the functional relation (via integration) do be able to do that.

Comment: @lemonrsiow I've editted a question with another way of thinking. Check the edit please, see if it helps.

Comment: ok, btw, could the method at http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=110425 work as well?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} & \cfrac{dA}{dr} = 2 \pi r  \\ & \cfrac{dC}{dt} = 2\pi r \\ & \cfrac{dA}{dt} = \cfrac{dA}{dr} \times \cfrac{dr}{dt} \\ & 4 = 2 \pi r \times \cfrac{dr}{dt} \\ & \cfrac{dr}{dt} = \cfrac{4}{2\pi r} \\ & \cfrac{dr}{dt} = \cfrac{2} {\pi r} \\ & r dr = \cfrac{2}{\pi } dt \\ & \int r dr = \int \cfrac{2}{\pi } dt \\ & \cfrac{r^2}{2} = \cfrac{2}{\pi} \times t \\ & r^2 = \cfrac{4}{\pi} \times t \\  & \text{Since t = 3 seconds} \ r^2 = \cfrac{4}{\pi} \times 3 = \cfrac{12}{\pi} \\ & r = \sqrt{\cfrac{12}{\pi} } \\ & \text{Since :} \ \cfrac{dC}{dt} = \cfrac{dC}{dr} \times \cfrac{dr}{dt} = 2 \pi \times \cfrac{2}{\pi r} \\ & \cfrac{dC}{dt} = \require{cancel}{2 \cancel{\pi} \times \cfrac{2}{\cancel{\pi}r}} \\  & \text{Put the value of r } \ \cfrac{dC}{dt} = \cfrac{4}{r} = \cfrac{4}{\sqrt{\cfrac{12}{\pi}}} \\ & \cfrac{dC}{dt} = \cfrac{4 \times \sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{3}} \end{align} $$

This is approximately equal to : $2.046 m/s $